# Switching between regular, dashed, dotted and the like in Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, plot-themes

I can combine several things to show them in one picture, e.g.

```
Show[{Graphics[{Black, Text["some text centered at {0,0}", {0, 0}]
               ,Red, Text["y=1", {3 Pi/2, 1}]
               ,Red, AbsolutePointSize[10]
               ,Point[{Pi, 0}]
               ,Text["here is Pi", {Pi, 0.4}]
               ,Black, Dashed
               ,Line[{{-Pi/2, Sin[-Pi/2]}, {Pi/2, Sin[Pi/2]}}]
               ,Green, Dotted
               ,Line[{{-Pi/2, Sin[-Pi/2]}, {3 Pi/2, Sin[3 Pi/2]}}]
               ,Blue
               ,Line[{{-3 Pi/2, Sin[-3 Pi/2]}, {Pi/2, Sin[Pi/2]}}]
               }
              ]      (* Graphics *)
     ,Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black]
     }
    ]                (* Show *)
```

to give me this not very meaningful picture:
[image: Graphics with dotted and dashed lines]

Now consider that I wanted to **draw the upper blue dotted line as a straight line** rather than a dotted one: **How to achive this?**

(I know one solution: Draw it before switching to dashed or dotted for the first time. Then it comes out as a straight line, but I consider this solution unsportsmanslike: I am looking for the right keyword to reset the way the line is dashed, dotted and the like and the online help has links to Dotted, DotDashed, Dashing, AbsoluteDashing, I expected and I missed a link to reset them all).

Comment: I marked this topic as a duplicate but if you disagree I'm open to discussion. :)

Answer (score 0):

The clue is **AbsoluteDashing[{}]**:

```
Show[{Graphics[{Black,Text["some text centered at {0,0}",{0,0}]
               ,Red,Text["y=1",{3Pi/2,1}]
               ,Red, AbsolutePointSize[10],Point[{Pi,0}],  Text["here is Pi",{Pi,0.4}]
           ,Black, Dashed, Line[{{-Pi/2,Sin[-Pi/2]}, {Pi/2,Sin[Pi/2]}}]
           ,Green, Dotted, Line[{{-Pi/2,Sin[-Pi/2]}, {3Pi/2,Sin[3Pi/2]}}]
           ,Blue, AbsoluteDashing[{}] 
           ,Line[{{-3Pi/2,Sin[-3Pi/2]}, {Pi/2,Sin[Pi/2]}}]
               }
           ]      (* Graphics *)
      ,Plot[Sin[x],{x,-2Pi,2Pi},PlotStyle->Black]
    }
   ]                (* Show *)
```

One might create a new keyword for it like this:

```
Straight=AbsoluteDashing[{}];
```

Bingo!

Comment: be sure to look at the responses to the other question. Using sub-lists is really cleaner.